# Create rule for one select in radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a rule where I would oblige the user to select only one radio value. However, when the button is cycled, it allows to select several and in addition to not let the user remove click

```js
var now = document.getElementsByName("now");
var day = document.getElementsByName("day");
var week = document.getElementsByName("week");

if ($("#now").prop("checked", true)) {

    day[0].checked = false
    week[0].checked = false

} else if ($("#day").prop("checked", true)) {

    now[0].checked = false
    week[0].checked = false

} else if ($("#week").prop("checked", true)) {

    now[0].checked = false
    day[0].checked = false

} else {
    console.log("undefined radio")
}
```

```html
<h1>Select action</h1>
<br>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot Now
    <input type="radio" name="now" id="now" value="now" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot 1x a day
    <input type="radio" name="day" id="day" value="0 * * * *" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot 1x a week
    <input type="radio" name="week" id="week" value="0 * * * 1" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Use the name property same of the radio button will allow you what you want to achieve without javascript.

Comment: I didn't understand, could you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do something like this you can achieve your goal.

```html
<h1>Select action</h1>
<br>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot Now
    <input type="radio" name="period" id="now" value="now" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot 1x a day
    <input type="radio" name="period" id="day" value="0 * * * *" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot 1x a week
    <input type="radio" name="period" id="week" value="0 * * * 1" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
```

P.S: If you need more to do commnet on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you give to all your `radio button` the same `name property`, you will be able to select only one of them.

For example give to all the `name="now"`.

```html
<h1>Select action</h1>
<br>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot Now
    <input type="radio" name="now" id="now" value="now" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot 1x a day
    <input type="radio" name="now" id="day" value="0 * * * *" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot 1x a week
    <input type="radio" name="now" id="week" value="0 * * * 1" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
```

In addition to your question about:

> not let the user remove click

This is because **radio buttons cannot be deselected**, you should use `checkbox` instead.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="your_id" name="your_name" value="your_value">
```

```html
<h1>Select action</h1>
<br>
<form>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot Now
    <input type="checkbox" name="now" id="now" value="now" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot 1x a day
    <input type="radio" name="now" id="day" value="0 * * * *" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot 1x a week
    <input type="radio" name="now" id="week" value="0 * * * 1" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
</form>
```

Comment: I added some information about the way to remove the click! Yw

Answer (score 1):

if your radio buttons have the same name then only 1 will be allowed to be clicked at a time

```html
<h1>Select action</h1>
<br>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot Now
    <input type="radio" name="now" id="now" value="now" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot 1x a day
    <input type="radio" name="now" id="day" value="0 * * * *" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
<label class="control control--radio">Shoot 1x a week
    <input type="radio" name="now" id="week" value="0 * * * 1" autofocus/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
```